# How to open flutter app from bubble overlay icon in android Kotlin plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies, kotlin-android-extensions

I edited flutter dependency [bubble_overlay 0.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble_overlay) using Kotlin and I need to reopen my app from bubble overlay function. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the open background app to the foreground using Android Kotlin.

```
val packageManager: PackageManager = this.packageManager
val intent1: Intent = 
packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app")!!
if (intent1 != null) {
    intent1.setPackage(null)
    intent1.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or 
                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
    this.startActivity(intent1)
}
```